# Glib's hashtable has size 0 after insertion

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I notice that calling the `g_hash_table_insert` on a globally defined hashtable results in no insertion in the hashtable:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
GHashTable* ht;
void f(void *p)
{
  g_hash_table_insert(ht,"A",p );
  g_hash_table_insert(ht,"b",p );
  g_hash_table_insert(ht,"c",p );

}
int main()
{
  GHashTable* ht=g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
  int i = 3;
  f(&i);
  printf("=> %d \n", g_hash_table_size(ht));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
(process:23035): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:04:13.945: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:23035): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:04:13.945: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:23035): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:04:13.946: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
=> 0
```

How should I avoid this problem and what are the failed assertions telling? How can the hashtable == NULL after being defined?

I compiled the program with

```
gcc -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic -o /tmp/a a.c
```

Comment: You need to care about scopes of your variables. You have a global variable `ht` that you use in `f()` and which is initialized to `NULL`. And you have a completely unrelated variable `ht` that happens to have the same name in `main`.

Comment: Generally you should avoid using global variables. Remove global `ht` and pass the local `ht` from `main` to your function `f`.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I avoid this problem

Do not alias global variables with local variables.

> what are the failed assertions telling?

That the first argument to `g_hash_table_insert(<this here>,` is equal to NULL.

> How can the hashtable == NULL after being defined?

It is never assigned to.

---

Remove variable definition from `main` and use the global variable evewhere.

```
int main() {
    ht = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
```